# Ballot box - conditional probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability

I indicate with $(w,b)$ a box with $w$ white balls and $b$ black balls.

> 1st step. From a box $(6,5)$ I extract one ball at random and put it back with another one of the opposite color. 
>   2nd step. Then I proceed with 4 extractions, without putting the balls extracted back into the box. If in the first three extractions one ball was black and two were white, what is the probability to get a white one at the fourth extraction?

After the 1st step I have a probability of $6/11$ to have $(6,6)$, $5/11$ to have $(7,5)$.
If in the first three extractions I extract one black and two white balls $(6,6) \leadsto (4,5)$ and $(7,5) \leadsto (5,4)$. So the probability to extract a white ball on the fourth extraction is
$$ \dfrac{4}{9} \dfrac{6}{11} + \dfrac{5}{9} \dfrac{5}{11} = \dfrac{49}{99}.$$
However the outcome should be $ \dfrac{319}{639}. $ What is wrong in my reasoning?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't use the information you got from the extractions about the colour of the originally extracted ball.

The prior probabilities for the first step are, as you wrote, $\frac6{11}$ for $(6,6)$ and $\frac5{11}$ for $(7,5)$. Now you draw one black and two white balls. The probability to draw them from $(6,6)$ is $\frac{\binom62\binom61}{\binom{12}3}=\frac9{22}$. The probability to draw them from $(7,5)$ is $\frac{\binom72\binom51}{\binom{12}3}=\frac{21}{44}$. Thus, the a posteriori probabilities are

$$
\frac{\frac6{11}\cdot\frac9{22}}{\frac6{11}\cdot\frac9{22}+\frac5{11}\cdot\frac{21}{44}}=\frac{36}{71}
$$

for $(6,6)$ and correspondingly $1-\frac{36}{71}=\frac{35}{71}$ for $(7,5)$. If we now draw another ball, the probability that it's white is

$$
\frac{36}{71}\cdot\frac49+\frac{35}{71}\cdot\frac59=\frac{319}{639}\;,
$$

in agreement with the result you expected.

Comment: Good thing you came across this problem! +1, of course.